# Taskqueue error while testing locally

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been developing with appengine for the past 6 months now and haven't had too many issues-- but I just switched my box setup from ArchLinux to a Linux Mint install and now am having a weird issue I haven't seen before.  I'm using the 1.8.0 python sdk.  I'm trying to dispatch tasks onto a named queue and am getting the following traceback:

```
ERROR    2013-06-05 14:53:33,762 taskqueue_stub.py:1892] Failed to dispatch task
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line     1890, in ExecuteTask
'0.1.0.2')
 File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 532, in add_request
headers_dict['Host'], urlparse.urlsplit(relative_url).path)
File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 580, in _resolve_target
raise request_info.ServerDoesNotExistError(prefix)
ServerDoesNotExistError: 15.bqdownloader-test
ERROR    2013-06-05 14:53:33,762 taskqueue_stub.py:1965] An error occured while sending the task "task16" (Url: "/_ah/warmup") in queue "download-queue". Treating as a task error.
```

My backends.py contains the following section that pertains:

```
- name: bqdownloader-test
  class: B1
  instances: 20
  options: dynamic
```

I've looked around and have found one mention of this error, but no fix.  Has anyone encountered this?  I don't really know what to do to address this issue.  Thanks in advance.